# mac gets stuck in a blue screen during boot

Tags: macos, boot, osx-leopard

a macbook pro 2008 unibody, after restart gets stuck in a blue screen. I used the Leopard disk and I verified and repaired permissions, which seem to be a problem, because the assistant found some wrong files. After restart I got the same problem.

After googling I reset PRAM and the other (I do not remember the name now). Same problem.

I check that I can boot in safe mode, although it is a lot slower.

So before anything I try to make a time machine backup, hoping that I can be done from safe mode.

First question: If it works, is it possible to do a clean leopard install (I do not like Snow) and migrate all user accounts from the backup, although it was done in safe mode?

Second question: I read about the feature "archive and install" from the leopard disc. Is it reliable? Because I am afraid of losing all data ...

Third question: I think this boot stuck has to do with the load of some program or service. It would explain why the computer does boot on safe mode and not in the normal one. I would then like to check what the computer loads during boot, but in more detail that with the information provided from /system preferecens/account/start, because there I removed everything. Where can I find more advanced information? And, if I remove programs from the safe mode, will it be effective druing the normal boot?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "blue screen?" As far as I know, there isn't a blue screen anywhere in the boot up process, except maybe the login screen if you've set the background to blue.

Comment: a last question, does the system store somewhere a log of what happens during the failed boot of the normal leopard mode?

Comment: this "blue screen" is an error, so the computer gets stuck and I can not do anything. you are fine if do not see it

Comment: Archive and install should be reliable... just check "Preserve user and network settings" as well during the installation. But as always, make a backup (doing it from safe mode should be ok). Also see http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1545, might be related.

Comment: ok, i will try and tell you about how the "should be" finally is, thx

Comment: Once you're in safe boot, try to diable automatic login. Maybe make a test user and set that to automatic login. (The only place in the boot sequence where there is a blue screen is when the computer logs in, so that's what I'm assuming this is happening.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your memory, maybe your memory is the problem

Comment: you are right, I forgot about the problem, and I thought it was solved :-P